# Does anyone have a working WatchedFileHandler and StreamHandler that is configured to work with Python's logging?

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I am trying to set up a logging handler that emits messages not only to the screen, but also to a logged file.  Since this is running an event driven simulator running 3 separate programs, I wanted to configure a WatchedFileHandler.  In an attempt to provide a minimal working set, here is the dictConfig setup:

```
# this is the sub_test.py logger setup
import os
import logging, logging.handlers, logging.config

def setup_logging(name, fname, args, mode='a', idtag=""):
  log_file = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]+".log"

  level = 'ERROR'
  if any(x in ["-v","--verbose"] for x in args):
    level = 'INFO'
  if any(x in ["-d","--debug"] for x in args):
    level = 'DEBUG'

  conf = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {'format':name+' (default): %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    'datefmt':'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'},
        'SH': {'format':name+' ('+idtag+'SH): %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                   'datefmt':'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'},
        'FH': {'format':name+' ('+idtag+'FH): %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                   'datefmt':'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'},
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': level,
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'SH',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'FH',
            'filename': log_file,
            'mode': mode,
            # more?
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': { # the root logger
            'level': level,
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propegate': False
        },
        name: {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'propegate': True
        },
    },
    #'propagate': True
  }

  logging.config.dictConfig(conf)
  logger = logging.getLogger(name)

  return logger
```

with a simple service program "sub_srv.py":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# a simple service example with some logging.
import sub_test
from time import sleep
import logging

LOG_NAME="test_log"

logger = sub_test.setup_logging(LOG_NAME, "test.log", ["-d"], mode='a', idtag="srv:")

logger.debug(" inside of the server")

sleep(1)

exit(1)
```

and a simple test program drive it:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
import sub_test
from time import sleep
import logging

LOG_NAME="test_log"

logger = sub_test.setup_logging(LOG_NAME, "test.log", sys.argv, mode='w', idtag="main:")

logger.info("here we go")

r = Popen("./sub_srv.py")

while True:
    if r.poll():
        break
    print("ok...")
    sleep(0.5)

logger.info("done...")

logging.shutdown()
```

I get the following output from the StreamHandler:

```
test_log (main:SH): INFO - here we go
ok...
test_log (srv:SH): DEBUG -  inside of the server
ok...
ok...
test_log (main:SH): INFO - done...
```

but I get the following output written to the "test.log" file:

```
test_log (main:FH): INFO - here we go
test_log (main:FH): INFO - done...
of the server
```

It is obvious to me from playing around that the output is not flushed and reopend as expected.  I have also tried various combinations of setting the propagate variable, but I have not been able to solve this.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference.  I got it working.  It appears that there is a bug in logging's WatchedFileHandler (which I will report).  The workaround is to simply change the 'mode'= mode (where the subroutines mode='w') to 'mode'='a' in the above example and do an os.remove(log_file) the first time around to clear the file.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Do you have any link to the bug report that you created for this?